# How to get a proper signature to authenticate to private websocket in Wootrade

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to authenticate to private websocket on wootrade

I am keep getting this error :

```
{
  'errorMsg': 'signature error',
  'event': 'auth',    
  'id': '123r',       
  'success': False,   
  'ts': 1644835797096
}
```

How should a message that I am hashing looks like and what should I correct in the code?

```
API = "xxx"
SECRET = "yyy"
APPLICATION_ID = "zzz"

timestamp_unix = int(time.time()*1000)

def on_message_woo(ws_woo, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)

def on_error_woo(ws_woo, error):
    print(error)

socket_woo=f'wss://wss.woo.network/v2/ws/private/stream/{APPLICATION_ID}'
ws_woo = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket_woo, on_message=on_message_woo, on_error=on_error_woo)

msg=f'|{timestamp_unix}' # I tried many combination here

signature1=hmac.new(SECRET.encode('utf8'), msg.encode('utf8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()
signature=base64.b64encode(signature1).decode('utf8')


def subskrypcje():
    time.sleep(5)
    ws_woo.send(json.dumps(
    {
    "id":"123r",
    "event":"auth",
    "params":{
        "apikey":API,
        "sign":signature,
        "timestamp":timestamp_unix
        }  
    }
                    ))
def ws_woo_start():
    ws_woo.run_forever()

t1=threading.Thread(target=ws_woo_start)
t2=threading.Thread(target=subskrypcje)


t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Below link to documentation
https://docs.woo.org/#auth

Answer (score 1):

After consulting with a friend we found a working solution

Subscription fuction should looks as fallow:

```
def subskrypcje():
    time.sleep(5)
    timestamp_unix = str(int(time.time()*1000))
    msg=f'|{timestamp_unix}'
    bytes_key = bytes(str(SECRET), "utf-8")
    bytes_msg = bytes(msg, "utf-8")
    signature = (
        hmac.new(bytes_key, msg=bytes_msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
        .hexdigest()
        .upper()
    )
   
    ws_woo_private.send(json.dumps(
    {
    "id":"123r",
    "event":"auth",
    "params":{
        "apikey":API,
        "sign":signature,
        "timestamp":timestamp_unix
        }
        }
         ))
```

The rest stays the same with this difference that hasing process is now in subscription(authantication) function